# Shucked WD Easystore works on PC but not on MyCLoud EX4100

Tags: nas

I recently shucked a 14tb EasyStore from BestBuy and taped the third pin. This drive now shows up on my PC. When I plug it into a WD My Cloud EX4100, the LED indicator glows solid red.
The drive shows up in the "Disk Status" under Storage Menu and indicates its 14tb available space.

But when I go to "Shares" to create a Share, it shows me all the drives except this one. Same under format menu. I see all drives except this one.

Its formated as NTFS if that helps.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong ?